# Override version of dependency package set by shlibs:Depends in deb

Tags: deb

I'm building a Debian package that depends on `libmysqlcppconn7v5`. I'm building it on Ubuntu which has `libmysqlcppconn7v5` 1.1.9, however it is intended to be installed on Debian which has `libmysqlcppconn7v5` 1.1.7.

`debian/control` contains following line:

```
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}, libmysqlcppconn7v5 (>= 1.1.7)
```

When the package is built it still has dependency `libmysqlcppconn7v5 (>= 1.1.9)`

How can I force it to have a dependency on lower package version than I have installed when building the package?

Comment: Which tool do you use to build the package?

Comment: I use command 'debuild -us -uc -b'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `shlibs:Depends` ends up specifying version 1.1.9 or later of `libmysqlcppconn7v5`, that (theoretically) means that the binary you built uses a symbol which is only available in version 1.1.9 or later. So your package won’t necessarily work on Debian with `libmysqlcppconn7v5` 1.1.7, even if you override the dependencies. (I’m qualifying this somewhat since the package doesn’t provide symbols or shlibs files, so the heuristics aren’t valid.)

As a general rule, you need to build your package on Debian if you want to install it on Debian. This isn’t all that hard to do on Ubuntu; take a look at `debootstrap`, `sbuild` and `pbuilder`. `pbuilder` in particular can easily be set up [to build on multiple distributions](https://wiki.debian.org/PbuilderTricks#How_to_build_for_different_distributions).

If you *really* want to override `shlibs:Depends`, you can edit the `.substvars` file that’s generated during the build, after `dpkg-shlibdeps` has run:

```
override_dh_shlibdeps:
    dh_shlibdeps
    sed -i s/1.1.9/1.1.7/g debian/yourpackage.substvars
```